# Why is the date object acting correctly in one instance but not the other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, logic

I have a problem I cant wrap my head around. The Date string is acting different in two instances where I think I am doing the same thing.

SO in essence, when I assign new Date("Jan 25, 2023 15:37:25").getTime() to countDownDate, the timer here (controlled by setInterval), will start where I expect it based on the string literal that is input into the date constructor. This will persist to count even on refresh.

The problem is when I need to calculate a future time dynamically. ALl of a sudden, when I calculate a dynamic future time string:

```
    var timer = new Date().getTime() + 620840000;
    var date = new Date(timer);
    var dateStr = date.toString();
    var countDownDate new Date(dateStr).getTime()
```

this no longer persists on refresh.

Now I am aware that in general you need to store the time in localstorage or even a server to allow the time to persist. which makes sense. I also understand that the timer is being recalculated every time the component is mounted. However, arent I doing the same exact thing by putting a static string literal into the date constructor? If its a matter of setting and resetting, shouldnt the date constructor with the string literal act the same way as a dynamically calculated string? pull

code here: https://github.com/Cerezze/timerTest

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    var timer = new Date().getTime() + 620840000;
    var date = new Date(timer);
    var dateStr = date.toString();

    var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 25, 2023 15:37:25").getTime(); // <-- Why does this persist on refresh
    /*var countDownDate new Date(dateStr).getTime();*/               // <-- and this does not persist on refresh?
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      console.log(days, hours, minutes, seconds); 
    }, 1000);
    return (distance) => {
        if(distance < 0){
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log('Expired');
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Re `new Date("Jan 25, 2023 15:37:25")`, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) If you're going to store a string for later parsing, best to store a format supported by ECMA-262, or a time value (ms since epoch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then the answer is that here

```
var timer = new Date().getTime() + 620840000;
```

you are creating a different date/time every time your javascript runs (new Date() will always be the present time according to the system clock)

```
var date = new Date(timer);
var dateStr = date.toString();
```

but here, you have a fixed date/time, which stays the same each time.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 25, 2023 15:37:25").getTime(); // <-- Why does this persist on refresh
```

Does that answer your question? I would have put this in a comment, but I wanted to show you in your code where I think your misunderstanding is

Comment: I see. It's The object that is created anew everytime the calculation happens. I think that makes sense. But is there no way excecpt to store it outside the app to keep the time persistent? In the case of the time being dynamically calculated

Comment: @chree Your best bet is to use localstorage, or if you have a backend you can set a cookie or save/retrieve it with a database